# Synology SSO Server

Tags: javascript, single-sign-on, synology

I have a Synology DS212j and already set up the apache and now also SSO Server. In the SSO Server Settings I added a new Application (Name, REdirect URI). My Code now is:

```html
<html>
   <head>
   <!-- include Synology SSO js -->
   <script src="http://NASADRESSE:5555/webman/sso/synoSSO-1.0.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
   function setButton (logged) {
      if (logged) {
         document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = '<button onclick="SYNOSSO.logout()">Logout</button>';
      } else {
         document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = '<button onclick="SYNOSSO.login()">Login</button>';
      }
   }
   function authCallback(reponse) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(reponse));
      if (reponse.status == 'login') {
         console.log('logged');
         setButton(true);
      }
      else {
         console.log('not logged ' + reponse.status);
         setButton(false);
      }
   }
   SYNOSSO.init({
      oauthserver_url: 'NASADRESSE:5555',
      app_id: '9a23da153795803e0334d9873b0013dd',
      redirect_uri: 'NASADDRESSE/?redirect', 
      callback: authCallback
   });
</script>

<h1> Syno SSO test</h1>

<p id='button'></p>

</body>

</html>
```

NASADRESSE is correct and my Rooter redirect port 5555 to 5000. Wenn I click login, a popup window opens where I can loggin with my NAS user. But it always says its a wrong password. But I entered the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - install the Directory Server package, enable LDAP server

2 - configure your DSM to connect to it (Control Panel-> Domain/LDAP)

3 - connect using the LDAP users

Answer (score 1):

Why in your script link included `.ch` but in your config the domain have no `.ch`

`http://NASADRESSE.ch:5555/webman/sso/synoSSO-1.0.0.js`

```
SYNOSSO.init({
  oauthserver_url: 'NASADRESSE:5555',
  app_id: '9a23da153795803e0334d9873b0013dd',
  redirect_uri: 'NASADDRESSE/?redirect', 
  callback: authCallback
});
```

May it go with wrong config?

Comment: I just forgot to remove my real domain contains .ch

Comment: it works the popup appears, but it always says my username ist wrong. I used admin and admin@domain.ch